# How to configure eslint in Bazel environment for typescript project

Tags: javascript, eslint, bazel, typescript-eslint

Tried configuring as below:

load("@npm//eslint:index.bzl", "eslint_test")

eslint_test(
name = "eslint",
config = "//ui/web:.eslintrc.js",
)

Ran command: `bazel test //ui/web:eslint`

ERROR: /home/projects/ui/web/BUILD.bazel:90:12: //ui/web:eslint: no such attribute 'config' in 'nodejs_test' rule
ERROR: error loading package 'ui/web': Package 'ui/web' contains errors

May i know the right configuration to run this eslint plugging with existing .eslintrc.js inside project

Bazel version in use: `5.x`